# Pattern matching on Oozie logs

Tags: perl, bash, unix, hadoop, oozie

**Oozie Command Used**

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -localtime | grep "2013-05-08" > Input.txt
```

**Oozie log (Input.txt)**

```
61-oozie     DProSUCCEEDED chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:47        2013-05-08 04:53
61-oozie     DPRUNNING chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:47        
61-oozie     DProcessSuspended chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:42        2013-05-08 04:48
61-oozie     DKILLED chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:07        2013-05-08 04:09
```

I want an extra column as "Status" which will store the status message as "SUCCESS/RUNNING/KILLED/SUSPENDED/Prep".

We will get the "**Status**" messages from **2nd column** as **<(processname)><(Status)>.**

I am not able to guess the delimiter from the above text . So as we can make use of AWK/cut/substring concepts.

```
Status messages are static . Job names are dynamic.
```

There will be **4 Status messages** .

- SUCCEEDED
- RUNNING
- Prep
- KILLED
- SUSPENDED

**Desired Output**

```
61-oozie     DPro chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:47        2013-05-08 04:53    SUCCEEDED
61-oozie     DP chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:47          -       RUNNING
61-oozie     DProcess chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:42        2013-05-08 04:48    Suspended
61-oozie    D chronicles      users     2013-05-08 04:07        2013-05-08 04:09    KILLED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracts desired status and puts it on the end of the line,

```
perl -pe 's/\B(succeeded|running|suspended|killed|prep)//i and $w=$1 and s/$/    $w/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/(\w+)(SUCCEEDED|RUNNING|Prep|KILLED|SUSPENDED)(\s+.+)$/\1\3 \2/g'
```

i.e. pre-status, status, post-status -> pre-status, post-status, status

Since you seem to have a difference between the status on input and desired output, e.g. 'ProcessSuspended' in and 'SUSPENDED' out, then you might also want to swap those:

```
sed 's/(\w+)(SUCCEEDED|RUNNING|Prep|KILLED|SUSPENDED)(\s+.+)$/\1\3 \2/g' | sed 's/ProcessSuspended$/SUSPENDED/g'
```

Or use Perl and do a lookup.